# Hibernate: PSQLException in a OneToMany relationship

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, kotlin

I have SpringBoot application in which I have a postgres database with a list of cinemas:

```
cinemadb=# select * from cinemas;
 id |           name            
----+---------------------------
  1 | London''s Electric Cinema
  2 | Alamo Drafthouse
  3 | Cineteca Matadero
  4 | Cine-de Chef
  5 | Castro Theatre
  6 | Cine Thisio
```

Each one of this cinemas displays one or more movies (which are in another database). I created a relational table:

```
cinemadb=# select * from cinema_movie;
 cinema_id | movie_id 
-----------+----------
         1 |        1
         1 |        5
         1 |        8
         2 |        2
         3 |        3
         3 |        9
         4 |        1
         4 |        2
         4 |        8
         4 |        9
         6 |        9
         7 |        9
         7 |        1
         8 |        1
```

In this last table cinema_id is a foreign key linked to id in cinemas table. movie_id is just an integer which represents the id in another database.

My entity representations:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cinemas")
data class Cinema(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        val id: Long = -1,
        val name: String = "",
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cinema", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
        @JsonIgnore
        val movies: Set<CinemaMovies> = HashSet()) {

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Cinema[id=$id, name=$name]"
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "cinema_movie")
data class CinemaMovies(
        @Id
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="cinema_id", nullable=false)
        val cinema: Cinema? = null,
        @Id
        @Column(name = "movie_id")
        val movieId: Long = -1): Serializable
```

The problem comes when I try to see the movies which belongs to an individual cinema:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending
>   to the backend.   at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:335)
>   ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]   at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441)
>   ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]   at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365)
>   ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]   at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:143)
>   ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]   at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:106)
>   ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]   at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
>   ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]  at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
>   ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.getResultSet(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:419)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:191)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:121)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:87)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:691)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:75)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2246)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:585)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:263)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:581)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:148)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.toArray(PersistentSet.java:195)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]   at
>   com.cinemaster.cinemamodule.controller.CinemaController.getCinemas(CinemaController.kt:27)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88)
>   ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:114)
>   ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:104)
>   ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835) ~[na:na] Caused by:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!     at
>   java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:133)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:320)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:263)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:258)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:129)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1183)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1153)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:828)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.readMore(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:140)
>   ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]   at
>   org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:109)
>   ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]   at
>   org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.read(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:67)
>   ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]   at
>   org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receiveChar(PGStream.java:306)
>   ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]   at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1952)
>   ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]   at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308)
>   ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]   ... 84 common frames omitted Caused
>   by: javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!   at
>   java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.GaloisCounterMode.decryptFinal(GaloisCounterMode.java:595)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.finalNoPadding(CipherCore.java:1116)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.fillOutputBuffer(CipherCore.java:1053)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:941)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:491)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/javax.crypto.CipherSpi.bufferCrypt(CipherSpi.java:779)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/javax.crypto.CipherSpi.engineDoFinal(CipherSpi.java:730)
>   ~[na:na]  at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2503)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLCipher$T13GcmReadCipherGenerator$GcmReadCipher.decrypt(SSLCipher.java:1913)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decodeInputRecord(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:262)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:190)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:108)
>   ~[na:na]  ... 93 common frames omitted

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: looks like having trouble with your ssl connection to the database: Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be ManyToMany relationship not OneToMany relationship. Also in a single entity class you cannot annotate two instance variable with @Id. You have to use create ManyToMany relationship.
Reference Example: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-many-to-many

Answer (score 0):

Create separate tables for cinema and movie and use @JoinTable instead of @JoinColumn

```
@JoinTable(
  name = "cinema_movie",
  joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "cinema_id"),
  inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id")
)
```